# Display Datarows in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

In a Windows forms application, how can i display an array of dataRows in dataGridView (Same number of columns)?

Tried this:

```
for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
{
    gridView1.Rows.Add(dataRowArray[i].ToString());
}
```

And this:

```
DataSource ds = new DataSource();
ds.Merge(dataRowArray);
gridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

No data is being displayed.

Comment: You have to Bind() after assining the DataSource..

Comment: There's no Bind() method in windows forms applications

Comment: this data that you are trying to bind.. where is the data coming from is this SQL Server or something.. ?? try looking at this link to help you / point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265059/faster-more-scalable-dataset-merge and if SQL Server look here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=132

Comment: well, i search a SQL server database and store the result rows in the array 'dataRowArray'. It's easier to display the dataset than just the search results. Thanks for the links. I'll try that.

Comment: not a problem.. have a good weekend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a slight change:

```
DataRow dRow;
for(i=0;i<results;i++)
      {
            dRow = returnedRows[i];
            secondForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dRow[0].ToString(), 
                dRow[1].ToString(),   dRow[2].ToString(), dRow[3].ToString());
      }
```

So it's working alright now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the array directly to the datasource?

```
gridView1.DataSource = dataRowArray;
```

Comment: Yes i did that too. No errors but no display either. I think i need to find a way to BIND the data to the grid somehow.